# Widget for var xyz not available after updating form (Firefox and IE only)

Tags: ajax, forms, primefaces, widget, updates

I'm facing a problem that occurs in the newest Firefox (59.0) but not in Chrome 64.0.

I could narrow it down to this code causing the problem. Afther clicking the button, the widget for var xyz is not there anymore, before it is (checked via Browser-Console -> PrimeFaces.widgets.xyz)

```
<h:form id="weekForm">
  <p:dialog id="projectDialog">
    <p:commandButton id="btnAddProject" update=":weekForm" value="add" 
    actionListener="#{logic.addProject}" partialSubmit="true" process="projectDialog" widgetVar="btnAddProjectWid"/>
  </p:dialog>
  ...
  <p:dialog id="violationRulesDialog" modal="true" widgetVar="xyz">...
  </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

update=":weekForm" is causing the problem. But I have no idea why.

Comment: Please create a real [mcve] and post PF version info and JSF version/implementation...

Comment: PF version is 5.0.4

Comment: So 5.1, 5.2, 5.3 ,6.0, 6.1 and 6.2 have the same problem? And "is causing a problem" is of-course waaaaay to vague... Errors? Server side? Client Side? WW3?

Comment: The error is -> Widget for var xyz not available (pops up in the console of the browser)

Comment: I tried to upgrade to 5.3 and 6.2, but then the application gets unusable.

Comment: You should normally always create a [mcve] and that should be easy to try in a newer version. Isolate the problem. See if this specific problem is fixed in a newer version...